# Was Dr. Ransom from C.S.Lewis' Space Trilogy based on J.R.R.Tolkien?

Tags: j-r-r-tolkien, cs-lewis, space-trilogy

When reading *Out of the Silent Planet*, it struck me that Dr. Elwin Ransom, the protagonist, was a philologist like C.S.Lewis' good friend J.R.R. Tolkien. I have seen much [speculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elwin_Ransom) to the effect, but nothing definitive.

Is there any documentation from interviews or letters that would confirm whether or not the character of Dr. Ransom is based on Tolkien?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to what I remember, he was a blend of Tolkien and C.S. Lewis himself.  Per Professor [Louis Markos' course on 'The Life and Writings of C.S. Lewis.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BD4N72)' (Part of the '[Great Courses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Great_Courses)' series.)

I don't have a wiki link, but in the Course Guidebook for the above course, he says "Ransom, whose character is based partly on Tolkien and partly on Lewis..." on page 28.

This also fits with the info you mentioned on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elwin_Ransom):

> This fits with the mention of his being "middle aged" at the time of "Perelandra" in the 1940s. Lewis might have conceived of Ransom as being his own age, i.e., born in 1898; J.R.R. Tolkien, one of Lewis's inspirations for the character, was born in 1892.

and

> Elwin Ransom may be based on C. S. Lewis' friend J. R. R. Tolkien ("Elwin" means "Elf friend" in Anglo-Saxon), though he seems to have autobiographical elements.

I will admit to not knowing exactly where they get the backup for this, but my best guess would be some of Lewis' own writings.  Sadly, I can't tell you exactly which ones.  I'll come back and edit this if I can find them, but hopefully a scholarly work such as Markos' trumps basic speculation :)

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that scholarly work is probably as close as I will get to an answer on this if the character wasn't based on Tolkien alone. I guess its not like he would come out and say, "Hey, its an amalgam of me and my buddy!"

Answer (score 6):

Lewis writes in his 1946 "A Reply to Professor Haldane," a response to a criticism of his *Space Trilogy*:

"...the hero (who is, by the way, to some extent a fancy portrait of a man I know, but not of me) is made to say that the sciences are 'good and innocent in themselves' (p. 248), though evil 'scientism' is creeping into them."

Obviously this doesn't specifically answer the question of whether Ransom is based on Tolkien, but it at least sheds some light on the question.